# How to disable Magento Warnings.

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, rwd-theme

[image: How to hide this Warnings]

Hi i have recently changed the magento theme. i was using rwd default theme now i decided to switch to sns_sport theme i have uploaded all the theme files to FTP i have solved all the errors and warnings but i don't know how to hide this warnings.

Answer (score 2):

You ought to change in the index.php
line  Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true); on the
 Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);

Comment: and if you have ini_set('display_errors', 1); change to 
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

Comment: Varien_Profiler::enable();

if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
this is the exciting code..

Comment: Can you test it by comment this code and add only 
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);

And if it will be works,, you need to change your vhost or .htaccess where you set Env -  MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE

Comment: i have also changed ini_set('display_errors;,0) it did not work

Comment: #Varien_Profiler::enable();

//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE']) || getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') == 'development') {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);
//}

Comment: i have followed the above code and changed to code to { Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false); My live website get 500  error code http://res.cloudinary.com/www-pantomath-xyz/image/upload/v1446806552/Screenshot_115_gn0n3p.png

Comment: http://codepaste.net/5y9bq7

Comment: http://res.cloudinary.com/www-pantomath-xyz/image/upload/v1446807072/fatalerror_hjzena.jpg

Comment: and change to
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

Maybe you need also enable maintenace flag for site and fix this bugs
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/maintenance-mode.htm

Comment: i Get this following error again..http://res.cloudinary.com/www-pantomath-xyz/image/upload/v1446807330/error_p05tqf.jpg

Comment: You need to enable maintenace mode and fix this bugs
https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/maintenance-mode.htm

Comment: When i set ini_set('display_errors',0); its shows 500 error

Comment: and with maintenance mode?

Comment: I have successfully put my live website on the maintenance mode. how to fix those bugs?

Comment: loca/Sns/Sport/Helper/Data.php
You need to check this file and debug it. line 180

Comment: The Code looks like this :public function _compileLess ($lessPath, $themeCssPath, $variables, $format) {
  $less = new lessc;
  $less->setVariables($variables);
  if($format) $less->setFormatter($format);
  $less->compileFile($lessPath, $themeCssPath);

Comment: Maybe it is a probłem with css compilation and you need to recompile your files via admin panel

Comment: Or you can try to take of this module Sns_Sport

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8zniyl

Comment: First i have to know what are those errors and i will try to slove it..